Random reboots on 20.04
My parents’ computer is having issues: it restarts randomly and unexpectedly. Most often, this happens when browsing the internet — when clicking on a link, it restarts at that exact moment of the click. Sometimes it happens while typing text. More rarely, it occurs while the computer is in sleep mode. Occasionally, it even restarts right when one clicks on "Shut Down" (which is very frustrating). There have also been instances of it entering a boot loop (restarting before completing the boot process).
(This issue resembles another one I found online, but it’s not the same kernel.)
The PC is old (9 years), with an Intel i3 processor and 4GB of RAM, and the system is installed on an SSD.
Here’s what I tried a few days ago when I was at my parents' during the holidays:

Upgraded the OS from 18.04 to 20.04. This didn’t change anything. I hesitated to upgrade to 22.04 since 4GB of RAM seems limiting.
Opened the case and cleaned it. I even removed the CPU fan/heatsink to thoroughly clean it, reapplied thermal paste, and reassembled everything. The temperature fluctuates between 30°C and 50°C (I didn’t measure the temperature before cleaning).
Ran Memtest86, which came back fine. The test completed without the system restarting.
Checked the latest logs using journalctl -b -1 -e: there’s nothing consistent across the various restarts. No error messages or warnings indicating an Ubuntu issue.
Performed stress tests (CPU via terminal and Disk via Disk Utility), and the system handles the load perfectly without restarting.

I’m now considering two possibilities: the BIOS or the power supply. For the BIOS, I followed these instructions and tried adding GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="libata.noacpi=1" — but it had no effect.
For the power supply, I tried plugging the PC into a different outlet in the house, but that didn’t help either.
Are there any other diagnostics I can try? I’m willing to replace the power supply (550W ATX), but I don’t understand why most restarts occur when performing an “action” (clicking or pressing a key). How could the power supply fail at the exact moment of clicking on a link? Could it be a sudden power demand that the supply can’t handle? But then, why does the system handle stress tests without issue? Or could that be related to the mouse?
Again, that's my parents' computer, I don't have direct access right now.

Welcome to ASK. Try to add more details to your question. Is it a controlled shutdown? What does 'last -x shutdown | less' report?  Is there a memory leak? What is the memory usage like? Use 'free' at regular intervals to watch for full memory usage.  You are looking for a steady increase.
